# linuxコマンドをansibleのyamlに置き換えた書き方を習得する方法や手順を教えてください。

Tags: centos, ansible

CentOS7をセットアップする手順を、ansibleのyamlに書き換えて自動化したいと考えています。

しかし、インストールしたい各コンポーネント
nginx・php-fpm・postgres・vftps・webmin
のリポジトリセット・インストール・各種設定

やテキスト置き換えなどを、ansibleのyamlに置き換える書き方がなかなか見つからないです。

linuxコマンドをansibleのyamlに置き換えた書き方を習得する方法や手順をがありましたら教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: ansible に限らないのですが、まず使いたいツールがあるなら [公式のドキュメント](https://docs.ansible.com/) を参照することをおすすめします。[日本語訳](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9_ja/index.html) も用意されているようです。 / ドキュメントが難しいようであれば「ansible 使い方」などでweb検索するといくつか解説記事が出てきます。https://ops.jig-saw.com/tech-cate/howto_use_ansible / これらを調べてみても分からない点がもしあれば、調べたり試した内容も含めた質問にすると回答が得られやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Module Index — Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html) から適切なモジュールを自分で探していくしかありません。Ansibleにはファイル操作やパッケージ操作など一般的な操作はモジュール群が存在します。役に立ちそうな主なモジュール群を紹介しておきます。

- Files modules
  ファイルのコピー(copy)やアクセス権の変更(acl)などが用意されています。
- Packaging modules
  パッケージ操作のモジュールが用意されています。CentOS7であれば[yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#yum-module)等を使うと良いでしょう。
- System modules
  cronやsystemdといったよく使われるようなシステム操作に関するモジュールが用意されています。
- Commands modules
  任意のコマンドを実行するためのモジュールです。適当なモジュールがなく、コマンドで設定するのであれば、こちらを使うと良いでしょう。

それぞれ、モジュールの細かい説明と例が用意されています。残念ながら、日本語版でも各モジュールの説明の日本語化はされていないようです。OSによっては使えない物や代わりを使う物(とくにWindowsは多い)がありますので説明はよく読んでください。